# Prove that the sequence defined by a recurrence is bounded

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

**Problem.** Let,
$$a(1)=1,\quad a(2)=e,\quad a(n+1)=\sqrt[3]{a^{2}(n)a(n-1)},\quad \forall n\geqslant 2.$$
Prove that $(a_{n})_{n=1}^{+\infty}$ is not convergent.

*EDIT:* @belows Thanks for the corrections, it looks like the sequence is convergent.

**My approach:**

- Calculating the first terms in the sequence we can see that

$$a(1)=1,\quad a(2)=e,\quad a(3)=e^{2/3},\quad a(4)=e^{7/9}, \ldots$$
so in particular we have
$$a(2)>a(3)<a(4)$$
Thus $(a_{n})$ is not monotocally increasing and decreasing, that means, the sequence is not monotocally.

- It's clear that $0<a_{n}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ so $(a_{n})_{n}$ is bounded below.

But, how can I prove that $(a_{n})_{n}$ is bounded above? I think we can see that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $a_{n}<3$ but I don't sure about this.

Comment: Hint: $a_{n+1}$ is always between $a_n,a_{n-1}.$

Comment: I'm not sure what boundedness has to do with the question, which I'm fairly sure is false, by the way! Why do you care about whether $(a_n)_n$ is bounded above?

Comment: By the way, the sequence is convergent.

Comment: @TheoBendit I only wanted to see if the sequence was upper bounded and lower bounded, bounded bounded sequence.

Comment: @mathproof Ah, I see. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Uhm because squeeze theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** (For bounded.) If $1\leq b,c\leq e$ then show $1\leq \sqrt[3]{b^2c}\leq e.$

---

The series is convergent. Show $x_n=\log a_n$ satisfies $$|x_{n+1}-x_n|= \frac13|x_n-x_{n-1}|.$$ Show this means $(x_n)$ is Cauchy, thus convergent.

---

An alternate approach, if the logarithm i seems too magical, is to let $$y_n=\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$$ and you get $$y_{n+1}=y_n^{-1/3}=\cdots=y_1^{(-1)^n/3^n}$$
Since $y_1=e, a_1=1,$
$$\begin{align}  a_{n}&=a_1\cdot\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k\\&=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}e^{(-1/3)^{k-1}}\\&=e^{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1/3)^{k-1}} \end{align}  $$

But the exponent is a geometric sequence, which converges.

Comment: What's the series?

Comment: What's the motivation for $x_{n}:=\log a_{n}$?

Comment: Oh! I understant it's because $x\mapsto \sqrt[3]{x}$.

Comment: $\sqrt[3]{a^2b}$ is a weighted geometric mean, so the logarithm is a weighted standard mean. Hence $x_n=\log a_n.$ @mathproof

Comment: Thank you! I understand @ThomasAndrews :-)

Comment: I just saw your new edition and it is a very nice solution. I like it because it comes out of making some calculations like I did at the beginning for the monotony, but I didn't see the pattern. Thank you very much @ThomasAndrews.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

Let $b_n :=\ln a_n$. Then $b_n$ satisfies the recurrence relation
$$b_{n+1}=\frac{2b_n+b_{n-1}}{3}$$

Comment: Since $$a(n+1)=\sqrt[3]{a^{2}(n)a(n-1)}\implies \log a(n+1)=\frac{2}{3}\log a(n)+\frac{1}{3}\log a(n-1).$$ Thank you (+1)!